# Após alert abrir modal

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando ao fazer o alert abrir o modal, mas não está funcionando.
Na função eu verifico se o campo `nnfe` está preenchido.

```
  function TransferenciaPedido() {
if ($("nnfe").val() == undefined) {
    alert("Preencha o número da NF-e corretamente.");
    $('#myModalNFe').modal('show');
}
else {

}}
```

Já tentei também colocar `return false;` porém mesmo assim o `modal` fecha.

Chamo a função em um `button` dentro do modal:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="TransferenciaPedido();" data-dismiss="modal">Concluir</button>
```

Comment: Coloca o código que chama a função pra ficar melhor

Comment: Sem o código da função fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Coloquei a função. eu chamo ela no onclick do button dentro do `modal`.

Comment: O alert dispara?

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros sim, ele apenas não volta o modal aberto.

Comment: Tenta .modal() sem o show

Comment: Ocorre a mesma coisa, já tentei criar uma `function` apenas para abrir, e chamar ela, porém também não funcionou.

Comment: Tira o data-dismiss="modal" e no else voce coloca .modal('hide');

Comment: Mariana você está comparando **undefined** com nada, pois o `val()` de **$("nnfe")** não está retornando nada, pois não é uma tag Html para ser chamada direta assim. Então está faltando ou um **`.`** ou um **`#`**. Está com o console do navegador aberto?

Comment: @LeAndrade Olha referente ao valor, está correto a comparação, eu só preciso que o modal seja aberto após o problema. somente isso.

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros fiz isso, e continua o mesmo comportamento.

Comment: Acho que sei onde está o problema. Tente tirar o `data-dismiss` do botão, e fechar o modal no `else` via JS.

Comment: Qual erro aparece no console do navegador? Tenta tirar o `data-dismiss` do botão também

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo eu tentei dessa forma, porém ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: @Maikeaerosmith já fiz isso, e mesmo assim o modal não continua aberto. Não aparece nenhum erro no navegador, o modal apenas fecha.

Comment: tira também o `$('#myModalNFe').modal('show');` haja visto que o modal vai permanecer aberto e só vai fechar no `else`
e tenta comparar com `undefined` com `===`, é mais seguro.

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: Disponha. O que estava ocorrendo é que você estava, inicialmente, exibindo o modal novamente antes de fechar pelo html do botão. Ai então você tirou o data-dismiss, mas ainda mandava abrir o modal por cima do modal que ainda estava aberto.

Answer (score -1):

Deixando a resposta aqui, para casos futuros de consulta.

O erro está em tentar exibir o modal com ele ainda aberto. Quando você chama a função o modal ainda não fechou, então acaba conflitando. A resolução seria:

```
function TransferenciaPedido() {
    if ($(".nnfe").val() === undefined) {
        alert("Preencha o número da NF-e corretamente.");
    } else {
        $('#myModalNFe').modal('hide');
    }
}
```

Html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="TransferenciaPedido();">Concluir</button>
```